# Teamviewer microphone issue

Tags: teamviewer

I am new with Teamviewer and I have some questions.

Lets say I have **laptop A** and **laptop B** (this is my office laptop), and I want to use laptop A to remotely control and work on laptop B.

For company's meeting we are using Teams, which is installed on office laptop (laptop B).

When I try to use Teams from remote laptop (laptop A), sending messages, files, pictures work fine, but when I try to call someone, Teams in using microphone from office laptop (laptop B).

Is it possible to use microphone from remote laptop and to speak free in Teams meetings on another laptop, in my case laptop B?

Thank you in advance!